# python #The description in the internet window called “This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.” can not be processed any more

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

python The description in the internet window called **“This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.”** can not be processed any more

**code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
cap['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
browser=webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap,executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe")
browser.get('https://www.naver.com/')
browser.set_window_size(533,533)
time.sleep(10)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: An error occurs.Traceback (most recent call last): File "web.py", line 8, in <module> browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:\\Users\\PPCCCP\\Downloads\\IEDriverServe‌​r.exe") File "C:\Users\PPCCCP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\l‌​ib\site-packages\sel‌​enium\webdriver\ie\w‌​ebdriver.py", line 82, in init raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) enium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode set

Comment: As error suggested, its due to Protected mode setting of IE browser. Follow below steps: 
Open IE Options -> Security -> Set all zones (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites) to the same protected mode, enabled or disabled should not matter
Also check zoom level should be 100%.